# handsent app suppresses SMS_RECEIVED broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

i have an app in the market that handles android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED broadcasts. now i realized, that the broadcast is not sent anymore (or at least i don't get it anymore) as soon as handcent sms is installed on the particular device.

1. how is it possible that an app can suppress a broadcast from being sent?
2. is there a way to still get the broadcast?

thanks 
simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how is it possible that an app can suppress a broadcast from being sent?

SMSes are sent as an ordered broadcast. High priority receivers can abort the broadcast, preventing lower priority receivers from getting their chance at it.

> is there a way to still get the broadcast?

Have your receiver have a higher-priority `<intent-filter>` than Handcent, which may or may not be possible.

Or, uninstall Handcent.

Comment: haha, i can not tell all my users to uninstall handcent :-) however, setting the filter priority to integer max, indeed solved the problem. thanks

Comment: Where did you set the priority to Integer.MAX_VALUE?