# SMS Received in my SMS app and in Hangouts, although I call abortBroadcast()

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, google-hangouts

I have an SMS blocker Android application developed myself which was working quite well capturing all the spams until recently Google updated its Hangouts app to work with SMSs.

The Problem: SMS is getting captured by both my app and hangouts! Even though the message is blocked by my app and stored in its private database, it is also present in the hangouts app and thus in the stock Messaging app at the same time.

Seems the `abortBroadcast()` isn't working any more. Everything was working perfectly before the Hangouts update.

I had also tried fiddling with `android:priority` but in vain.

Comment: This is on-topic. OP is asking why another app is conflicting with their usage of the Android APIs, and what can be done to fix it.

Comment: Look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021492/enabling-sms-support-in-hangouts-2-0-breaks-the-broadcastreceiver-of-sms-receive

Answer (score 7):

Hangouts uses the maximum possible priority (999 per [the Intent-Filter docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html)) and therefore you cannot abort it on <4.4 releases. On 4.4+, only the [default SMS app](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#SMS) ([blog post with details](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)) can receive SMS notifications - users would need to set your app as the default SMS app for your app to function correctly (although it should function as expected if that happens).

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Setting the same priority (999) to our app would fix the problem or it won't?

Comment: @oracleruiz - the ordering for matching priorities is random so you won't get consistent results.

Comment: Could be possible to disable Hangouts notifications for certains incoming SMS?

Comment: @ianhanniballake - you mean I just can't block an sms in <4.4(devices with Hangouts installed)? Not even if i give mine the priority of 999?

Comment: @oracleruiz - I dont want my users to disable Hangouts because then it will become a limitation for my app :)

Comment: I discovered even a Hangouts version with priority `MAX_INT` - no way out in this case.

Answer (score 0):

When you register receiver, set priority of filter to INTEGER.MAX_VALUE.
Now abortBroadcast() will work;

```
    receiver = new HightPrioritySmsReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    filter.setPriority(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```