# Unable to catch SMS received with android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I am not able to catch the intent when a SMS is received. Below is my code of the service. I am able to catch the "`Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON`" and "`Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`" but I am NOT able to catch the `SMS_RECEIVED` intent "`android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`".

Sincerely appreciate any hints on what I am doing wrong here?

```
public class SmsCatcher extends Service{

BroadcastReceiver myBroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i("myBroadcast SmsCatcher", "Entered onReceive method");
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.i("myBroadcast SmsCatcher", "Caught SCREEN_OFF");
        }
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Log.i("myBroadcast SmsCatcher", "Caught SCREEN_ON");
        }

        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
            Log.i("myBroadcast SmsCatcher", "SMS_RECEIVED");
        }
    }
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i("neil SmsCatcher", "Entered onCreate() in 'SmsCatcher extends Service'");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Entered onCreate() in 'SmsCatcher extends Service'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    registerReceiver(myBroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
    registerReceiver(myBroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    Log.i("neil SmsCatcher", "Entered onDestroy() in 'SmsCatcher extends Service'");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Entered onDestroy() in 'SmsCatcher extends Service'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


}
```

**UPDATE 1**: Adding some more information from my ongoing debug:
I used the App [Internal Broadcasts Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lt.andro.broadcastlogger&hl=en) to see there is a broadcast when there is a text message received and I dont see anything, very strange. What could be the reason?
I have other SMS apps installed (Hangout, AT&T Messages) - these cant suppress the broadcast can they?

**UPDATE 2: FOUND PROBLEM BUT DONT KNOW HOW TO SOLVE**
I uninstalled the [Google Hangouts (replaces Talk)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.talk) app and it WORKS!!! 
Any solution around this? (should i be opening a separate thread as per stackoverflow rules?)

**UPDATE 3: FOUND ROOTCAUSE**  (with help below of course, thank you)
It turns out that because of the new Google Hangouts App, I needed to [setPriority(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#setPriority%28int%29). I found the solution at [Enabling SMS support in Hangouts 2.0 breaks the BroadcastReceiver of SMS_RECEIVED in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021492/enabling-sms-support-in-hangouts-2-0-breaks-the-broadcastreceiver-of-sms-receive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register the `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` intent filter,only if you have registered it you can able to check the intent in the `onRecive` like

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED);
this.registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, filter);
```

**Update From the question:**
It turns out Google Hangouts App aborts the sms broadcast as soon as it receives it,So disabling SMS support in Hangouts 2.0  may fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I added the registerReceiver(...) but I still dont catch the Intent. I updated the issue with some more debug, I dont think a broadcast is being generated, strange :S

Comment: I am marking yours as the answer as your way of setting the IntentFilter allowed most easily to setPriority(int) [as per my UPDATE 3 above]. Thanks.

Comment: I'll add it in the answer too for future help

Answer (score 2):

You did not register the intent-filter:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // ..
    registerReceiver(myBroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
    registerReceiver(myBroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
    registerReceiver(myBroadcast, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")); // missing in your code
}
```

And please check your permissions for `android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Good catch, thanks to @insomniac below also, but I added registerReceiver(...) but I still do not trigger on that Intent filter. Is it correct to use "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" or is it supposed to be something else?

I already have the permissions in my manifest file:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

Comment: I have a lead, please see UPDATE 2 above. Any ideas?